# How to add a list<string> that orders file paths that are getting counted inside the cycle asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, list

Inside a foreach loop, i am counting and getting the full path of files with similar names, and I need to access them later so I want to make a list that saves them, and my question is how can I do this?
I´ve been trying to do it like this.

```cs
protected void ShowPng(string pathPgnImg)
{
    btnNextPage.Visible = true;
    string sImageName = "";
    string sImagePathImages = Server.MapPath("Anexos/");
    string pngFile = "";
    List<string> pngs = new List<string> { pngFile };
    string FileWithoutPath = Path.GetFileName(pathPgnImg);
    string fileWithoutPathAndExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileWithoutPath);
    if(fileWithoutPathAndExt + "_pag" + LblHiddenImagePageNumber != fileWithoutPathAndExt + "_pag" + "" )
    {
        DirectoryInfo AnexoDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(PathForPdf);
        FileInfo[] filesInDir = AnexoDirectory.GetFiles(fileWithoutPathAndExt + "_pag" + "*.png");

        foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
        {
            pngFile = foundFile.FullName;
            pngs = new List<string> { pngFile };
        }
        
        string sFileExt = Path.GetExtension(pngFile);

        pngFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pngFile);
        m_sImageNameUserUpload = pngFile + sFileExt;
        m_sImageNameGenerated = Path.Combine(sImagePathImages, m_sImageNameUserUpload);

        //Literal1.Text += "<img src=" + '"' + pngFile + '"' + "/>";
        imgCrop.ImageUrl = "Anexos\\" + Path.GetFileName(pngFile);

        if (m_sImageNameUserUpload != "")
        {
            pnlCrop.Visible = true;
            imgCrop.ImageUrl = "Anexos/" + m_sImageNameUserUpload;
            Session["ImageName"] = m_sImageNameUserUpload;
        }
    }
}
```

You can find what I mean in these lines here:

```cs
foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
{

    pngFile = foundFile.FullName;
    pngs = new List<string> { pngFile };
}
```

So what can I do? the output right now for it is although it adds the value it doesn't save it and add the other ones just adds that one to the list.

Comment: Inside the `foreach` you recreate the list with only the current `pngFile` in it. create the list outside of that loop (or even outside of the method if you want to keep adding between calls) and then inside the `foreach` use `pngs.Add(pngFile);`

Comment: oh i see, thank you so much @Knoop will do it right away please make it an answer so i can upvote it and accept it, if you want ofcourse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Knoop for the answer to this simple question.

Turns out the only problem i was having was i wasn´t adding up to the list count.

So start by making a list:

```
List<string> Files = new List<string>;
```

Since i was trying to add the value of a variable that kept updating trough a foreach loop, ill use that example:

```
foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
            {

                pngFile = foundFile.FullName;
                pngs.Add(pngFile);
            }
```

Just to explain what i changed from the original question post to this answer was this line:

```
pngs.Add(pngFile);
```

with the name of the list and the `.ADD` it keeps adding the pngFile value everytime the loop restarts.

Once again thank you to @Knoop for the help.

I hope this helps some of you too.